# Copy the header for non blank values in the column by using R

Tags: r

I have data set like

| A header | Another header | Another header |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | NA |
| NA | Na | NA |
| 5 | NA | 7 |
| NA | NA | NA |
| NA | 3.5 | NA |

Result I want is get copy headers for all non-blank values

| header | Another header | Another header |
| --- | --- | --- |
| header | Another header |  |
|  |  |  |
| header |  | Another header |
|  |  |  |
|  | Another header |  |

Can any one help to get the codes for this problem

Comment: With the information provided it is next to impossible to sort out what the exact problem is and how to solve it. You would need to share the xlsx file, the exact code you are using for an input, the output you obtain, and the output you desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try the following base R option

```
df[] <- ifelse(!is.na(df), names(df)[col(df)], "")
```

which gives

```
> df
  A B C
1 A B
2
3 A   C
4      
5   B
```

** Dummy Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(A = c(1, NA, 5, NA, NA), B = c(6, NA, NA, NA, 
3.5), C = c(NA, NA, 7, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-5L))
```

Comment: @ThomaslsCoding - Thanks alot  but I am trying it on my data and getting the below error

>In matrix(value, n, p) :
  data length [267050] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of columns [3]

My data has row = 175 and column = 1526

Comment: @SYEDSALMAN Please `dput` your data

Comment: @ThomaslsCoding : Thanks alot. It is working now :)